# How to create a dynamic selection list in Ansible

Tags: python, ansible, jinja2

I am attempting to create an installation ansible playbook that automates the installation of many different installers.  I am able to figure out the installation of these programs just fine, but I'm having a tough time creating a selector to select which installers to use.

In a previous playbook I was able to find a trick by using a `vars_prompt` which then creates a variable with a value that you type in which looks like this:

```yaml
vars_prompt:
  - name: "san_location"
    prompt: "\nWhat SAN(s) do you want to mount?\n1- SAN1\n2- SAN2\n3- Both\n"
    private: no

tasks:
  - name: Add SAN1 MDC1 to host file
    lineinfile:
      state: present
      path: '/etc/hosts'
      line: 192.168.x.x   SAN1
    when: ( san_location == "1" ) or
          ( san_location == "3" )
```

This allows you to select a 1, 2, or 3 and execute tons of tasks based upon a user input/selection.  Now I am trying to do this but by taking a playbook that has a "find" module in it that looks for all of the installers in a directory and lists them to be selected to install.

Here is the find task:

```yaml
tasks:
  - name: Register all files
    find:
      paths: "{{ installer_path }}"
      patterns: '*.pkg,*.dmg'
      file_type: file
    register: installers
```

Is there any built in way in Ansible to make a list of these files selectable and then execute tasks based upon that?

Comment: No, but you could use a [`pause`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/pause_module.html) in lieu of your `vars_prompt` to list all those files and make a number correspondance with them, then prompt the user for a number, as you did before.

Comment: How would I create a list that corresponds to the files found?  I don't see a way to do that dynamically...

edit: I should say a "user-friendly" selectable list

Comment: There is none, hence why my comment starts with _No_. The best you could have is a list like you'd do it in markdown (e.g. `1. path/to/file \n 2. path/to/file2` – replace the `\n`with new lines), but then you'll still have `assert` the validity of the user answer (e.g. is it an int, in bounds, etc).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For example, given the directory

```yaml
shell> tree installers/
installers/
├── A
├── B
└── C
```

The playbook below

```yaml
shell> cat pb.yml
- hosts: localhost

  tasks:

    - pause:
        prompt: "Select installer {{ item|basename }}? [y/n]"
      register: out
      loop: "{{ query('fileglob', 'installers/*')|sort }}"
      loop_control:
        label: "{{ item|basename }}"

    - debug:
        msg: "install {{ item.item|basename }}"
      loop: "{{ out.results }}"
      loop_control:
        label: "{{ item.item|basename }}"
      when: item.user_input == 'y'
```

select the first two installers (A, B) and skip the last one (C)

```yaml
shell> ansible-playbook pb.yml 

PLAY [localhost] *****************************************************************************

TASK [pause] *********************************************************************************
[pause]
Select installer A? [y/n]:
y^Mok: [localhost] => (item=A)
[pause]
Select installer B? [y/n]:
y^Mok: [localhost] => (item=B)
[pause]
Select installer C? [y/n]:
n^Mok: [localhost] => (item=C)

TASK [debug] *********************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => (item=A) => 
  msg: install A
ok: [localhost] => (item=B) => 
  msg: install B
skipping: [localhost] => (item=C) 

PLAY RECAP ***********************************************************************************
localhost: ok=2    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

---

If you want to use the module `find` the playbook below gives the same results

```yaml
- hosts: localhost

  tasks:

    - find:
        paths: "{{ playbook_dir }}/installers"
        recurse: true
      register: installers

    - pause:
        prompt: "Select installer {{ item|basename }}? [y/n]"
      register: out
      loop: "{{ installers.files|map(attribute='path')|sort }}"
      loop_control:
        label: "{{ item|basename }}"

    - debug:
        msg: "install {{ item.item|basename }}"
      loop: "{{ out.results }}"
      loop_control:
        label: "{{ item.item|basename }}"
      when: item.user_input == 'y'
```

---

The next option is to select a single installer

```yaml
- hosts: localhost

  vars:

    installers: "{{ _find.files|map(attribute='path')|sort }}"

  tasks:

    - find:
        paths: "{{ playbook_dir }}/installers"
        recurse: true
      register: _find

    - pause:
        prompt: |
          Select installer [{{ range(1, installers|length + 1)|join(',') }}]
          {% for i in installers %}
          {{ loop.index }} ... {{ i|basename }}
          {% endfor %}
      register: out

    - debug:
        msg: "install {{ installers[out.user_input|int - 1]|basename }}"
```

Comment: Thank you for this! I used your find example and it works well.  Was able to edit it and make it work exactly how I wanted so far. Now to build out the playbook even more...

Answer (score 1):

There is no built-in easy way of achieving this, no, but you can do the same as you did with `vars_prompt` in a [`pause`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/pause_module.html) task.

Then, to ensure the viability of the given answer, you should [`assert`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/assert_module.html) it (e.g. to validate the answer is indeed an integer, in the bounds of your files list, ...).

Here would be an example of this:

```yaml
- find:
    paths: "{{ installer_path }}"
    patterns: '*.pkg,*.dmg'
    file_type: file
  register: installers

- pause:
    prompt: >
      Please select a file

      {% for item in installers.files %}
        {{ loop.index }}. {{ item.path }}
      {% endfor %}
  register: selected_installed

- assert:
    that:
      ## Since `{{ 'a' | int == 0 }}`, this first assertion will discard
      ## both `0` as an answer or any other invalid character
      - selected_installed.user_input | int - 1 >= 0
      - installers.files[selected_installed.user_input | int - 1] is defined

- debug:
    msg: >-
      You choose the file
      `{{ installers.files[selected_installed.user_input | int - 1].path }}`
```

And here is an example of running those three tasks:

```
TASK [find] **************************************************************
ok: [localhost]

TASK [pause] *************************************************************
Please select a file
  1. /tmp/baz.pkg
  2. /tmp/foo.pkg
  3. /tmp/bar.pkg
:
2^Mok: [localhost]

TASK [assert] ************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => changed=false 
  msg: All assertions passed

TASK [debug] *************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => 
  msg: You choose the file `/tmp/foo.pkg`
```